# How to access data from FLUIDTEMPLATE file and render that content in our desired file?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-9.x

I have my package from sitepackagebuilder (v9.5.14). I no good at Typoscript. I am using the optional menu navigation file **MainBefore.html** (my desired file) from *bootstrap_package* which I put in my stpkg extension because this file is globally available in the FE alongside main menu. I try to explain my doubt in the two following examples.
First one is clear to me. usually I do things like this, (My only known typoscript way to access and render things).

Example 1:
**In typoscript**

```
lib.stdContent = FLUIDTEMPLATE
lib.stdContent {
 file = EXT:sitepackagebuilder/Resources/Private/Partials/Page/DropIn/Navigation/Data.html
   variables {
      mylabel = TEXT
      mylabel.value = Label coming from TypoScript!
   }
}
```

**In Data.html**

```
<h4>Hello TYPO3</h4>
<h3 hidden>{mylabel}</h3>
```

**MainBefore.html**

```
 ....
 <div class="from-data-file"><f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.stdContent" /></div>
 ....
```

The above example will work.

*Example 2:*

**But this following example is my doubt.**

```
page.10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
page.10.variables.userInfoForChat = COA_INT
page.10.variables.userInfoForChat {
    10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
    10 {
        file = EXT:company/Resources/Private/Partials/Page/DropIn/Navigation/Data.html
        variables {
            mylabel = TEXT
            mylabel.value = Label coming from TypoScript!
        }
    }
}
```

**How can I access variables in Data.html and render content in MainBefore.html like example 1?** Correct me If I am wrong
*Both files are in same location.*

Answer (score 0):

First: you are doing very complicated things. normaly stacking templates inside each other is not necessary. so the main question would be: **What do you intend to do?**

Then we can find a simple way to do it.

I try to identify your intention:

you have a main template (main = main for this example, otherwise it is just a small part of the general page rendering) where you want to have a variable, which is filled from another template, where some variable is inserted.

Some information is missing as these would not be necessary when all values are static like in your example.
There must be something non static as you use a uncached `COA_INT` and the name `userInfoForChat` hints to something user specific, which of course is not cachable.

My question is: why do you put a complete fluid templating in the variable, when it should be enough to have only some uncached values in it and stay with just one set of fluid template. (That set already could consists of template, layout and a lot of partials)